# how to use textspan for middle text of get.dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter

On deleting account i want a default dialog for confirmation  and i have used Getx dialog

but here i want some style in middle text like textspan how to do it?

Like middle text of dialog should be shown

Are you sure to delete account of **David**?

```
void getDeleteConfirmationDialog(){
    Get.defaultDialog(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      title: 'Delete User',
//for bellow i want to use text pan and show user's name as bold
      middleText: 'Are Your sure to Delete record of '+users[selectedIndex.value].name+'?',
      confirm: ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()async{
        deleteRecord();
        Navigator.of(Get.overlayContext!).pop();

      }, child: Text('Sure, Delete')),
      cancel: OutlinedButton(onPressed: (){
        Navigator.of(Get.overlayContext!).pop();
      }, child: Text('Cancel')),
    );
```

Comment: nop..its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get has another way to set dialog which is called `Get.dialog`.
With this type of dialog, you can set column or stack or anything you need inside your dialog.
here is an example:

```
Get.dialog(
        // for dismissing dialog when touching outside of dialog
        barrierDismissible: false,
        Dialog(
          backgroundColor: AppColor.transparent,
          child: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async => false,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                ***************************YOU CAN USE TEXT SPAN HERE*************
                 Text("No Internet Connection"),
                  
                  SizedBox(height:10,),
                  Image.asset(AppImage.internetConnection,height:30),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child: Text("Please check your connection again,or connect to wi-fi.",),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: AppColor.grey,
                    thickness: 1,
                  ),
                  Inkwell(
                    onTap: () {
                        Get.to(() => const AllVideoScreen());
                    }, child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      height:50,
                      width: 30,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: AppColor.blackWhite,
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                         "Refresh",
                        
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
```